# Console warning when using NSLayoutAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, nslayoutconstraint, nslayoutanchor

I am using `NSLayoutAnchor`'s `constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter` for building my layout.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToSystemSpacingAfter(safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, multiplier: 1)
])
```

It actually works, but it throws a warning in the console after I activate the constraints:

> Aligning the right edge of a [custom view]
>   with the right edge of a [second custom view]
>   is not recommended. Use an explicit constant for your constraint to override this.

How can I make this warning disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `NSLayoutAnchor.constraint(equalTo:constant:)` instead of that method.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 0)
])
```